# How to add child object to textbox in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to add child object to a TextBox, but this code gives an error

How can I achieve this?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</asp:TextBox>`
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to set the value of the TextBox? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's because TextBoxes don't have child object.
I think what you want is something like this:
<code>
    <asp: Label runat="server" Text="Label" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</code>

Answer (score 1):

TextBox and Label are two different controls. You cant nest a Label inside a text Box.

Eg:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> 
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
```

What do you want to do here?

Answer (score 1):

As there are some of the ASP.NET controls like Linkbutton which allows you to hold HTML controls inside them

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server"  CssClass="remove">
    <span><font color="#fb4202">x</font> Remove</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

but it is not possible to hold a asp:Label in a asp:Textbox control

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible. While WPF has a framework that enables this kind of things, HTML and thus ASP.NET does not.

If you are trying to set the text, try this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text="abc" />
```

Else, just put them side by side:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Label" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Textbox is a Editable Control and Label is non-Editable Control, so you can't put Label inside TextBox. You can Put Label Just Before The Textbox as :

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter Text"><asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server"/>
```